connection bms 1s and tp4056 together
i'm noob with the circuits and diy in general. I'm asking this question here after a lot of searches between Google and YouTube on the subject. I'm trying to use a parallel of 2 18650 lithium ions to power a circuit. To avoid under voltage of lithium batteries, I thought I would use a BMS 1S and a TP4056 module to handle the charge. So I was wondering how these components should be connected together? Thanks in advance

And do you have any knowledge about the TP4056 module if it already has a BMS? When buying components, you often have manuals that explain how to connect them. Do not buy ones that have no documentation how to use them.

well I have documentation, but as far as I know (just googled) tp4056 with protection only have over voltage protection (?). so I thought to add a bms to have a under voltage protection. do you mean the bms it's useless since tp4056 circuit protection already has a integrated bms? Or did I misunderstand?

Either your module has protection or not. We don't know what module you bought and if it integrates a BMS or not, or anything else about it. If your module has documentation, it should be in that documentation.
